# Convert eloquent result to associative array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

How can convert the result from eloquent to associative array. I need to select tow column and have one as key and another as value. Here is the closet I got, however the value is an array. I want it to be only "my_value" column.

```
$array = Post::select('my_key','my_value')->get()->keyBy('my_key')
```

Comment: What results do you get with this code? And what do you expect to get? Give some examples.

Comment: I was looking for `array:2 [▼
  "key1" => "value1"
  "key2" => "value2"
]`

Comment: The above approach after converting toArray was giving me: `array:2 [▼
  "key1" => array:2 [▼
    "my_key" => "key1"
    "my_value" => "value1"
  ]
  "key2" => array:2 [▼
    "my_key" => "key2"
    "my_value" => "value2"
  ]
]`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use `lists` (Laravel 5.1) or `pluck` (Laravel 5.2+):

```
$array = Post::lists('my_value', 'my_key');
```

or

```
$array = Post::pluck('my_value', 'my_key');
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like lists have been renamed to plunk, I just modified it a bit `$array = Post::plunk('my_value', 'my_key')->toArray();`

Comment: Just wanted to point out for any future people: @Mehdi's answer is a typo.  It is "pluck" not "plunk".

Comment: @Mehdi `pluck` not `plunk`

Answer (score 6):

I found a way to do so, I'm not sure whether it's proper way to do this performance wise though...

```
$array = Post::select('my_key','my_value')->get()->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
            return [$item['my_key'] => $item['my_value']];
        })->toArray();
```

Comment: You can just $array = $array ->toArray() to convert object as string. Its buildin method.